# How to insert multiple rows into an Order table?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, sqlplus, data-modeling

So I set up a simple database and I am at the point where I am trying to test that it is working correctly. I am trying to figure out how I get multiple entries into an Order table. I need to have an order# and be able to order multiple items and use multiple shippers and such. I just can't seem to figure out a way to get the data into my DB properly.

Below is how I have my DB set up. Could someone please explain to me how to get the my test data into the DB.

Here are the reference tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Product_Table (
ProductID INT NOT NULL,
Product_Name char(50) NOT NULL,
Product_Cost number(9,2) NOT NULL,
Product_In_Stock INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Products_PK PRIMARY KEY (ProductID)
);

CREATE TABLE Payment_Terms_Table (
PayTermNum INT NOT NULL,
Payment_Time_Frame CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Payment_Terms_PK PRIMARY KEY (PayTermNum)
);


CREATE TABLE Shipper_Table (
ShipperNum INT NOT NULL,
Shipper_Name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Shipper_Phone CHAR(22) NULL,
CONSTRAINT ShipperNum_PK PRIMARY KEY (ShipperNum)
);

CREATE TABLE Supplier_Table (
SupplierID INT NOT NULL,
Supplier_Name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Sup_Address CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Sup_City CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Sup_State CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Sup_Zip CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
Sup_Phone  CHAR(22) NULL,
ShipperNum INT NOT NULL,
PayTermNum INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Supplier_PK PRIMARY KEY (SupplierID),
CONSTRAINT ShipperNum_Relationship FOREIGN KEY (ShipperNum)
        REFERENCES Shipper_Table (ShipperNum),
CONSTRAINT PayTermNum_Relationship FOREIGN KEY (PayTermNum)
        REFERENCES Payment_Terms_Table (PayTermNum)
);
```

Here is my Order table:

```
CREATE TABLE Order_Table (
OrderID INT NOT NULL,
ProductID INT NOT NULL,
SupplierID INT NOT NULL,
Wholesale_Price NUMBER (9,2) NOT NULL,
Units_Ordered INT NOT NULL,
Order_Date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
Order_Received DATE NULL,
CONSTRAINT Order_PK PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
CONSTRAINT ProductID_Relationship FOREIGN KEY (ProductID)
    REFERENCES Product_Table (ProductID),
 CONSTRAINT SupplierID_Relationship FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID)
    REFERENCES Supplier_Table (SupplierID)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a defined one table to hold Orders, so you can have only one Item per Order.  Normally we handle this scenario by having two tables: a Header with the information for the whole Order and a Line table for each ordered Item.

```
CREATE TABLE Order_Header (
OrderID INT NOT NULL,
Order_Date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
Order_Received DATE NULL,
CONSTRAINT Order_PK PRIMARY KEY (OrderID) 
)
/

CREATE TABLE Order_Line (
OrderID INT NOT NULL,
LineNo INT NOT NULL,
ProductID INT NOT NULL,
SupplierID INT NOT NULL,
Wholesale_Price NUMBER (9,2) NOT NULL,
Units_Ordered INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Order_Line_PK PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, LineNo),
CONSTRAINT Order_Line_Header_FK FOREIGN KEY (OrderID)
    REFERENCES Order_Header (OrderID)
CONSTRAINT ProductID_Relationship FOREIGN KEY (ProductID)
    REFERENCES Product_Table (ProductID),
 CONSTRAINT SupplierID_Relationship FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID)
    REFERENCES Supplier_Table (SupplierID)
)
/
```

I have declared a composite primary key because it is easier to understand what's happening.

Now that you have two tables you can easily create orders with more than one line.

---

On the subject of normal practice, an Order should have a CUSTOMER.  That would be an attribute of  ORDER_HEADER.  Also you have a SHIPPER table but don't use it.  Again that would probably be an attribute of  ORDER_HEADER.

Also your naming convention is ugly.  There's no need to include `_TABLE`: just name the objects for teh things they represent.  Likewise your foreign key needs are opaque; it doesn't matter so much in this toy example but in a real database you will find it helpful to specify the child and parent tables in the FK names.